# Flutter is not loading devices and says 'Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock...'

Tags: flutter, command, loading, startup

My Flutter project is not loading devices and says 'Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock. Here is what I've done so far but it didn't work:

I've removed this file:

/bin/cache/lockfile

I've opened the terminal and wrote:

killall -9 dart

Please let me know what else I could try to get this working?

[image]

Comment: Does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Android Studio, go to Preferences and inside framework go in Flutter, then set the SDK path. It may be not there.

It often happens when we upgrade or downgrade SDK, it removes the path. Also try Flutter clean and Flutter doctor before setting the Flutter SDK path.

[image: Add Flutter SDK Path]

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm having a similar problem with IntelliJ. To fix this I currently restart the Flutter daemon by using "Find Action.." (press shift two times in a row) and search for the "Restart Flutter Daemon" command.

[image: Restart Flutter Daemon]

At the moment it is just a temporary fix, but should hopefully enable you to work again.

Comment: Thanks for the info about restarting the Flutter daemon by using 'Find Action...'.  It restarted but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Damn, for me that solves the infinite device loading error. Do you see your devices when you type `flutter devices` in your terminal? Another way to start your app is via the cli by running `flutter run` or `flutter run -d DEVICEID`. It is not as well integrated but might work.

Comment: When I type 'flutter devices' into the terminal it says: 'Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock...'. It also says this when I type in 'flutter run'

Answer (score 0):

I removed flutter and then reinstalled it and then it finally loaded the devices.